# Need to advice applying .disabled in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I run Woocommerce website and want to disable a specific input on the checkout page.

Woocommerce can set shipping method by country.

I have the default country set as S,Korea, and the shipping options for Korea are displayed.

However, where if i select US, Shipping method will see shipping options according to the US.

So, Shipping method of US is not displayed by default.

And it will only be displayed if visitor select "US" as the shipping country.

Here I want to disable the input field that is only displayed when the shipping country is US.

I can hide this input field using CSS, or even get rid of it.

However, the reason I want to disable it is that the post office is temporarily paralyzed due to Corona.

I want to inform visitor that the shipping method is not only express shipping, there is also free shipping, but it is temporarily unavailable.

My website structure is as follows.

Default (S.korea)

```
<td data-title="shipping">
    <ul id="shipping_method" class="shipping__list woocommerce-shipping-methods>
        <li class="shipping_list_item">
            <input id="shipping_method_0_free_shipping1">
            <label class="shipping_list_label" for="shipping_method_0_free_shipping1">
        </li>
    </ul>
<td>
```

If choose shipping country as US

```
<td data-title="shipping">
    <ul id="shipping_method" class="shipping__list woocommerce-shipping-methods>
        <li class="shipping_list_item">
                <input type="radio" id="shipping_method_0_free_shipping3"> <--- want to disable this
                <label class="shipping_list_label" for="shipping_method_0_free_shipping3"> 
        </li>
        <li class="shipping_list_item">
                <input type="radio" id="shipping_method_0_flat_rate2"
                <label class="shipping_list_label" for="shipping_method_0_flat_rate2">
        </li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

Country selector

```
<span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
    <select name="billing_country">
        <option value>Select Country</option>
        <option value="US">US</option>
        <option value="KR" selected="selected">Korea</option>
        <option value="CA">Canada</option>
    </select>
```

And I tried the javascript below.

```
<script>
     const target = document.querySelector('#shipping_method > li:nth-child(1)');
target.disabled = true;
</script>
```

```
<script>
     const target = document.querySelector('#shipping_method_0_free_shipping3');
target.disabled = true;
</script>
```

but these code not work.

I'd like to get some advice on which part I should check.

Comment: You say the input is not shown by default. So why should it be shown when you set disabled to false? Disable and hidden are two completely different things

Comment: Shouldn't you set disabled to true if you want it to be disabled? And the issue with your first example, `'#shipping_method > li:nth-child(1)'` is that you left out the input. E.g. `'#shipping_method > li:nth-child(1) input'`. I'm also confused between being disabled and hidden.

Comment: Disabling an element and not displaying it are two different things.

Comment: @Thallius  Hi, I forgot to change the code to true.
It is not disabled even when disabled=true.

Comment: Hi, @j08691 Thanks for answering. the problem is not disabled even when disabled=true. 
 i forgot to change false to ture.  also I tried `'#shipping_method > li:nth-child(1) input' but still not work.

Comment: “*… it will only be displayed if visitor select "US" as the shipping country.*” - where is this element that has the “US” as an option?

Comment: Hi @Andy, I've updated a more details body.

Comment: Hi, @DavidThomas. The country can be selected via the "billing_country" selector. I have updated the body. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try to do it with css styling, place your inputs inside a div and give the div a disabled class, all you have to do is to assign the disabled class to the div via java script

```
div.disabled {
  opacity: 0.6;
  pointer-events: none;
}


html 
<div id="#mydiv"> <input name="input-1"/></div>

//jquery code 
$("#mydiv").addClass("disabled"); 
//javascript code
document.getElementById("#myDiv").classList.add('disabled');
```

Comment: I would really like to understand people who are just randomly giving -ve reviews are doing it based on what basis !  I am not going to look into my crystal ball to figure out each one objection or review is based on what and certainly allowing these kind of -ve reviews without any kind of justification sounds silly as well

Comment: That should be very obvious to you. You are uisng jQuery in your answer. The question isn't tagged [tag:jquery], jQuery isn't necessary here (or even particularly useful), and you answer is based on totally different HTML. I wonder why up to this point it was only -1.

Comment: So all you do care is jquery versus javascrip ignoring that this is only suggestion to try css as a different approach ? seriously are you for real

Comment: Hello. @Sameh Thanks for answering. 

I was new to CSS being able to use it like this.

As you answer, by adding the disable class, the input is disabled.

But if the country changes, WooCommerce refreshes(ajax) the class containing the input to calculate the shipping cost.

Then, the deactivated input is activated again.

Is there any way I can apply it in this case? I don't know about Jquery, but it doesn't matter if it works.

Comment: You need to set the selection event on the drop down list, resolve the selected value, if it is US then add the disabled class, else remove the disabled class. something similar to that <select onchange="onCountryChanged()"> or you can use jquery something similar to that $('#select-id').change(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});

Answer (score 0):

****Try this**  (Updated Answer)**

```
<input id="name" type="text"/>

const myInput = document.getElementById("name")
const inputDisabled = true

if (inputDisabled) {
    myInput.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
} else {
    myInput.removeAttribute("disabled");
}
```

Comment: I am correcting the negative review because your answer is correct, it didn't deserve it and i hope you do the same for me as well , regards as for element just edit you answer to document.getElementById() to be more clear for readers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello. Thank you for answer. 

I tried applying the updated code, but it still doesn't work.

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code.

It seems to me that some feature of WooCommerce is re-enabling this.

When I first entered the checkout page, I saw that the input was disabled.

BUt if the country changes, WooCommerce refreshe(Ajax) it to calculate the shipping cost.

This refresh will cause the disabled input to become active again.

How to do l solve in this case...